# Python regex: flat text file with multiple space but I want to keep name with only one space

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I have some lines like this :

```
00000     SomeText    00000    0000
00000     Some'Text    00000    0000
1111     Some Text Text    33    4444
```

For now, I'm using:

`match = re.search(r'(\d+)\s+([\w@._]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)', line)`

But I'm missing all the "Some Text" and "Some Text Text".

Between each cols, there is 2+ whitespace.

I want to catch:
- first digit
- text with only one space
- second digit
- third digit

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `text with only one space` mean you only want to match the third line in your example?

Comment: Yes, I want all the 3 lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\d+)\s+(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

Or, if these are whole lines/strings (it may require `re.MULTILINE` or `re.M` option and `[^\S\r\n]+` instead of `\s+` if you need to handle a single multiline text):

```
^(\d+)\s+(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1TaScr/1)

The main point here is `\S+(?:\s\S+)*`:

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `(?:\s\S+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces

Comment: Thanks!
I discovered there is some new characters to cactch (as ï / [ / ] / etc.) so your answer is great!

Comment: Ha, and if there is some "Some    Text  Text" with 2 or 3 spaces?

Comment: @MrKjuo Check the field separators in your file, are they really spaces or tab characters? If they are tabs, you may simply use `^(\d+)\t(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)$`.  Another regex solution is possible if you can literally describe what each field consists of, or at least all but one. If you are sure the first, thrid and fourth fields are digit only chunks of text, and the second field can have any chars, just use `.*?` -> `^(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all `\s+` with `\s{2,}` and add `\s` to the second column group:

```
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\s{2,}([\w@._\s]+?)\s{2,}(\d+)\s{2,}(\d+)', line)
```

Another option is to use `re.split` instead of `re.search`:

```
columns = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of a rather long regex, I would recommend splitting each line on `\s{2,}` and testing each column separately

```
text = '''00000     SomeText    00000    0000
00000     Some'Text    00000    0000
1111     Some Text Text    33    4444'''

for line in text.split('\n'):
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)
    if c1.isnumeric() and ('  ' not in c2) and \
       c3.isnumeric() and c4.isnumeric():
        print(line)
# prints:
00000,SomeText,00000,0000
00000,Some'Text,00000,0000
1111,Some Text Text,33,4444
```